# Why is this code executing?

Tags: php, html

Seems like the last stretch is getting harder!

So I have if statements and inside those statements code should execute if they are true.  The problem is the code is executing even though its no true.

Code that execute even though Spproved is set to 1

```
if($user_data['permissions'] >= 1)
{
    // If users permission is 1 or 2 they get a field for inputting the index # and a button to change the approve field from 0 to 1 may need to make a new field to record who approved it....

    //Determine if the order is already approved.  If not approved show index field and allow user to approve it with index number
    if($data2[0]['Approved'] == 1)
    {
        echo " <font color=\"green\"> Approved";
    }
    else if($data2[0]['Approved'] == 0)
    {
        echo " Not Approved.  Supply an index number and click approve to authorize this order to be completed.";

        if (empty ($_GET) === false) 
        {
            $required_fields = array('IndexNum');
            foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value)
            {
                if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true)
                {
                $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
                break 1;
                }
            }

            if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true)
            {            
                echo 'Index has been updated and Order is now set to Approved';
            }
            else
            {    
                if (empty($errors) === true)
                {   
                    $indexnum=$_GET['IndexNum'];
                    $approvedby=$user_data['lname'];
                    $vendorid1= $_GET['hidden1'];

                    update_approved($approvedby, $indexnum, $vendorid1);
                    header('Location: index.php');
                    exit();        
                }
                else if(empty($errors) === false)
                {
                    echo output_errors($errors);
                }
            }
        }

        ?>            
         <form name="approveform" method="GET" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="<?php echo $id;?>">"
        Index Number*: <input type="text" name="IndexNum">&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Approve" action="">
        </form>

<?php }     
}

if($user_data['permissions'] == 2)
{
    // If user is permission 2 they can have a button to say shipped... Do I need to record who shipped it?  for now nah.  Would be nice to input a data of arrival though.  I will think on it .... pretty lazy
    if($data2[0]['Approved'] == 1)
    {
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Confirm order has been ordered";

    if(isset($_GET['Ordered']))
    {
        $vendorid1=$_GET['hidden1'];

        echo $vendorid1;
        //update_shipped($vendorid1);
        //header('Location: index.php');
        //exit();
    }    
    ?>

    <form name="approveform" method="GET" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
    <input type="submit" name="Ordered" value="Ordered" action="">
    </form>

    <?php            
    }    
}
```

IT shows Approved in green on the form and the Ordered button comes up fine.  When I click the submit button the code in the else if($data[0]['Approved'] == 0) activates instead of the code  the isset.  Approved is set to 1 So I have no idea why that code is running.....

Value of `print_r($data2)` is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [VendorName] => Newegg [DateRequested] => 2013-09-25
[DateNeeded] => 0000-00-00 [Shipping] => Standard [VendorNumber] => 123123 
[VendorFax] => NA [VendorAddress] => 1 ave new [VendorCity] => socorro 
[VendorState] => nm [VendorZip] => 87114 [EquipmentConsumable] => Consumable 
[GasType] => propane [GasLocation] => United States [UNMTag] => 0 
[EquipmentLocation] => [index] => 414141 [totalcost] => 129.88 
[Approved] => 1 [Shipped] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: Show the output of print_r($data2).

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [VendorName] => Newegg [DateRequested] => 2013-09-25 [DateNeeded] => 0000-00-00 [Shipping] => Standard [VendorNumber] => 123123 [VendorFax] => NA [VendorAddress] => 1 ave new [VendorCity] => socorro [VendorState] => nm [VendorZip] => 87114 [EquipmentConsumable] => Consumable [GasType] => propane [GasLocation] => United States [UNMTag] => 0 [EquipmentLocation] => [index] => 414141 [totalcost] => 129.88 [Approved] => 1 [Shipped] => 0 ) )

Comment: What you have is a logical error. Step through your code debugging every condition and assignment and you'll have your answer. No reason to have others do that for you.

Comment: Pretty sure its not a logical error I think Jason got it right.  Thanks for your input

Comment: @HELPMEPLEASE You're using the wrong comparison operator. That's a logical error. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error vs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error. Read the section about debugging logical errors. "One of the ways to find these type of errors is to output the program's variables to a file or on the screen in order to define the error's location in code". Sounds exactly like what happened here.

Answer (score 1):

Use strict comparisons, `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`. PHP tends to evaluate 1 and 0 as boolean unless told explicitly otherwise.

Also, with functions like `empty()`, you can change:

`if( empty($_GET) === FALSE )` **to** `if( !empty( $_GET ) )`
`if( empty($_GET) === TRUE )` **to** `if( empty( $_GET ) )`

As they return boolean.

Since you are using $_GET, make sure all the variables you need per pass are in the url. Since the form elements can only pass the nested input elements, you may require more hidden information to pass after submit. Also, you should probably put the file name in `action=""` or omit it from the form tag.

Comment: or just (empty($_get))

Comment: Alright though this fixed it but does not seem to.  So what it does with the === is shows the correct information but now if I use the submit button it does not process information just returns the page.

This now happens in both functions the Approveform used to work before the === was added.  Now both forms just go to a blank page on submit.

Comment: Well that narrows it down. @Snowburnt I actually was talking about the first conditionals that use integers.

Comment: They are all in the URL perfectly.  Im going to upload some images for you.  I really have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: You also use `$_GET['success']`, this doesn't look like it ties to anything.

Comment: Ya was planing to use that but decided to switch...  I guess there is no solution to this issue.  Ill come up with something else...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not going to solve your problem but....

```
                                                         You have an extra "
                                                             right here
                                                                  |
                                                                  V
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="<?php echo $id;?>">"
    Index Number*: <input type="text" name="IndexNum">&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="Approve" action="">
```

Comment: Oops Thanks!  Did not see that.